# determine pitch, yaw, roll from up front right

Tags: opengl

In my didactic openGL appl , I have some objects on the scene, and when I click on one of them I want my camera to look at that object. For that after I determine the clicked object , I compute the up , front and right vectors of the camera  and then I need to be able to calculate the  pitch, yaw, roll angles of the camera. However I am quite clueless about how could I do that , so any help would be great .

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to do all these calculations. simply use `glLookAt()`. it takes the position of the camera, the position of where you want to look and the up vector and orients the model view matrix accordingly.

If you really want do it the hard way, look at my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575216/how-to-get-camera-up-vector-from-roll-pitch-and-yaw).

Comment: I'd do it like this , if it were up to me.....but I'm supposed to learn more , by doing this way .

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of calculating backwards. From the `front` vector you should be able to deduce `yaw` and `pitch` relativly easy.

If your coordinate system has x and z as the floor

```
yaw = atan2(front.z, front.x);
```

The pitch can be calculated by normalizing `front` and using asin

```
front.normalize();
pitch = asin(front.y);
```

If I have time later I'll look into calculating the `roll`

*Otherwise has shoosh a good suggestion to use `gluLookAt`*